# Rails path returning ".id" instead of "/id"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following routes:

```
get 'requirements/' => 'requirements#index'
post 'requirements/' => 'requirements#create'
delete 'requirements/:id' => 'requirements#destroy'
```

The problem is that `requirements_path(id)` is returning `/requirements.id` instead of `/requirements/id`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: @ruby_newbie no need for that, specially considering I wont need a show action in this app. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was name the route:

```
delete 'requirements/:id' => 'requirements#destroy', as: :requirement
```

I believe this was due to the fact that `requirements_path`was already being used. Please leave a comment if you know more about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your issue by naming the route, but the better fix here would be to use the Rails `resource` route tool, which will name your routes for you. That will also let you use the correctly-named `requirement_path(id)` helper (note the singular `requirement`, not `requirements`).

In your routes.rb:

```
  resources :requirements, only: [:show, :create, :destroy]
```

Then `requirement_path(1)` will generate `/requirements/1` as you expect.

P.S. The reason you're getting `requirements.1` when you use `requirements_path(1)` is because all route helpers accept an additional argument, `format`, which becomes the format (e.g. `.xml`) on the end of the path. Since your route helper does not expect any route parameters, it turns the ID into that format.

Answer (score 0):

requirements_path (plural) is an index route and so passing it a value causes Rails to tack it on as a format, as explained in other answers. What you want to use is requirement_path (singular), which is the naming for show/destroy named path methods.